# How to move view using gesture detector and animation

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I have added one `view` in linear layout and I want to move that `view` at run time in the direction user pushed it, for that I have added `onTouchListner` on view, as well as I have defined one gesture detector.

On `gestureDetector`'s `onFling` method I have started translation animation on view

```
@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
float velocityY) {

mX = e2.getX();
mY = e2.getY();

TranslateAnimation transA = new TranslateAnimation(
                    e1.getX(),e2.getX(),e1.getY(),e2.getY());

transA.setDuration(1000);
transA.setAnimationListener(MainActivity.this);
mBtn.startAnimation(transA);

return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
}
```

translation animation works well but after animation view remains on its original position. To move view to destination location I am setting views x & y property to mX and mY

```
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
mBtn.setX(mX);
mBtn.setY(mY);
}
```

but this is not working properly. please help, If there is any other way to achieve this please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a button that is moving in there as well? I see a mBtn. Note that a view animation is only going to transform the place where a view is drawn and not where it actually is (hence a button clickable area won't move with a button). You could try doing transA.setFillAfter(true), that should stop it from going back to the original position, but I believe the clickable area will stay the same. Hence you should try doing a property animation, as it will update the properties of the view and not just where it is drawn. Doing a viewpropertyanimator might be easiest as you are animating x and y. You can read more here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html